# How to have the name of the polygons all the time in Mapview R?

Tags: r, mapview

I am using mapview in R to plot maps. I have more tha 100 polygons and I want to show them on the map with the names on it every time.  But I couldn’t find a solution to this issue. Any idea?

```
mp<-st_read('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mgaitan/departamentos_argentina/master/departamentos-buenos_aires.json',stringsAsFactors= FALSE)
mapview(mp,zcol='cabecera')
```

I attached the image of my map. I want the names of the polygons (such as "Tres Arroyos") in every polygon ALL THE TIME.

[image]

Comment: Which names? Are the names an attribute of the map data? Are you trying to label the polygons? Or is it a legend with 100 items? Can you post an image of what you've got and maybe some code too?

Comment: Thank you very much @Spacedman for your comments. I have already edited the question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use leaflet and the function addStaticLabels() from the package leafem to add labels to the polygons.

Something like this:

```
mp=st_read('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mgaitan/departamentos_argentina/master/departamentos-buenos_aires.json',stringsAsFactors= FALSE)
map = leaflet(mp)
mapview(dataX, zcol = "cabecera", addStaticLabels(map=map, data=mp, label = mp$departamento))
```

It may be be cluttered and ugly, but the labels will be there.